# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added In Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am trying to find the correct version configurations in order to utilize the Xamarin.Facebook.Android package and still be able to support Lollipop (the latest version seems to only support Nougat).

I installed many necessary packages, but now I get an error while building that I can't seem to get rid of.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added :  Lbolts/AggregateException;

My googling suggested that this error is generally caused by having multiples of one package. I couldn't figure out how to fix the problem.

Here is the list of installed packages for the project. Any help would be much appreciated! (Sorry for the length)

AWSSDK.APIGateway                                 {3.3.8}
 
AWSSDK.CognitoIdentity                            {3.3.2.14}
 
AWSSDK.CognitoIdentityProvider                    {3.3.6}
AWSSDK.CognitoSync                                {3.3.1.23}
AWSSDK.Core                                       {3.3.17.8}
AWSSDK.DynamoDBv2                                 {3.3.4.17}
AWSSDK.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication           {0.9.1}
AWSSDK.IdentityManagement                         {3.3.4.3}
AWSSDK.S3                                         {3.3.10.4}
AWSSDK.SecurityToken                              {3.3.3}
AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService                  {3.3.0.21}
AWSSDK.SQS                                        {3.3.2.7}
Bolts                                             {1.4.0.1}
Microsoft.Bcl                                     {1.1.10}
Microsoft.Bcl.Build                               {1.0.21}
Microsoft.CSharp                                  {4.4.0}
Microsoft.Net.Http                                {2.2.29}
Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms                       {2.0.0}
Microsoft.Win32.Primitives                        {4.3.0}
NETStandard.Library                               {2.0.0}
Newtonsoft.Json                                   {10.0.3}
PCLCrypto                                         {2.0.147}
PCLStorage                                        {1.0.2}
PInvoke.BCrypt                                    {0.3.2}
PInvoke.Kernel32                                  {0.3.2}
PInvoke.NCrypt                                    {0.3.2}
PInvoke.Windows.Core                              {0.3.2}
 
SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green                         {1.1.8}
SQLitePCLRaw.core                                 {1.1.8}
SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android                {1.1.8}
SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android           {1.1.8}
System.AppContext                                 {4.3.0}
System.Collections                                {4.3.0}
System.Collections.Concurrent                     {4.3.0}
System.Collections.NonGeneric                     {4.3.0}
System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter               {4.3.0}
System.Console                                    {4.3.0}
System.Diagnostics.Debug                          {4.3.0}
System.Diagnostics.Tools                          {4.3.0}
 
System.Diagnostics.Tracing                        {4.3.0}
 
System.Globalization                              {4.3.0}
 
System.Globalization.Calendars                    {4.3.0}
 
System.IO                                         {4.3.0}
 
System.IO.Compression                             {4.3.0}
System.IO.Compression.ZipFile                     {4.3.0}
System.IO.FileSystem                              {4.3.0}
System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives                   {4.3.0}
System.Linq                                       {4.3.0}
System.Linq.Expressions                           {4.3.0}
System.Net.Http                                   {4.3.2}
System.Net.Primitives                             {4.3.0}
System.Net.Sockets                                {4.3.0}
System.ObjectModel                                {4.3.0}
System.Reflection                                 {4.3.0}
System.Reflection.Extensions                      {4.3.0}
System.Reflection.Primitives                      {4.3.0}
System.Resources.ResourceManager                  {4.3.0}
System.Runtime                                    {4.3.0}
System.Runtime.Extensions                         {4.3.0}
System.Runtime.Handles                            {4.3.0}
System.Runtime.InteropServices                    {4.3.0}
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation {4.3.0}
System.Runtime.Numerics                           {4.3.0}
System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters           {4.3.0}
System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives           {4.3.0}
System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms           {4.3.0}
System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding             {4.3.0}
System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives           {4.3.0}
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates     {4.3.0}
System.Text.Encoding                              {4.3.0}
System.Text.Encoding.Extensions                   {4.3.0}
System.Text.RegularExpressions                    {4.3.0}
System.Threading                                  {4.3.0}
System.Threading.Tasks                            {4.3.0}
System.Threading.Timer                            {4.3.0}
System.Xml.ReaderWriter                           {4.3.0}
System.Xml.XDocument                              {4.3.0}
System.Xml.XmlDocument                            {4.3.0}
Validation                                        {2.4.15}
Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable  {23.4.0.1}
Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs                {23.4.0.1}
Xamarin.Android.Support.v4                        {23.4.0.1}
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat              {23.4.0.1}
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView               {23.4.0.1}
Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable           {23.4.0.1}
Xamarin.Facebook.Android                          {4.16.1}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed the issue. It was being caused by having the package Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 installed before installing Xamarin.Facebook.Android.

Unistalling Xamarin.Facebook.Android and Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (and all dependencies of both) then reinstalling Xamarin.Facebook.Android cleared the error.